# Using an ExternalFunction in a pyomo constraint

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization

### Issue summary

I'm new to Pyomo and I'm trying to solve a non-linear optimization problem where the constraints are arbitrary Python functions whose values must lay in the interval `[1/8, 1]`. In my case, these functions are `scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator`s, and because the problem gives them, I can't change them too much.

I know about [`ExternalFunction`](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library_reference/aml/index.html#pyomo.environ.ExternalFunction.__init__)s, but I must be doing something wrong because I'm getting a `KeyError: 'pyomo_socket_server'`. As far as I understand it:

- `f` can be any Python callable.
- `g` is the gradient vector. In my case, as all functions are `R -> R`, that is a list of length 1 with the first derivative of `f`.
- `h` is the hessian matrix, but we should only return the upper triangular portion, column-wise. In my case, as all functions are `R -> R`, that is a list of length 1 with the second derivative of `f`.

I'm using `ipopt`, which works correctly as I've tried other problems with non-linear constraints (but without `ExternalFunction`s) that work.

Do you spot any obvious errors? How can I make this work?

### Minimal (non) working example

```
import numpy as np
from pyomo.environ import (
    Any,
    ConcreteModel,
    ExternalFunction,
    NonNegativeIntegers,
    NonNegativeReals,
    Param,
    Set,
    SolverFactory,
    Var,
    maximize,
    summation,
)
from scipy.interpolate import PchipInterpolator

# Generate example data
bounds = {
    "g": (800, 2150),
    "v": (1200, 2150),
    "em": (1300, 2350),
    "e": (1400, 2550),
    "ep": (1500, 2450),
    "d": (1800, 2650),
}

y_bounds = {
    "g": (0, 2),
    "v": (0, 4),
    "em": (0, 3.5),
    "e": (0, 3.5),
    "ep": (0, 1.75),
    "d": (0, 1.5),
}

curves = {}
for (product_, (lower_x, upper_x)), (lower_y, upper_y) in zip(bounds.items(), y_bounds.values()):
    x = np.arange(lower_x, upper_x, 1)
    y = (1 - 1 / (1 + np.exp(-0.01 * (x - x.mean())))) * (upper_y - lower_y) + lower_y
    curves[product_] = PchipInterpolator(x, y)

curves_derivatives = {product_: curve.derivative(nu=1) for product_, curve in curves.items()}
curves_derivatives_2 = {product_: curve.derivative(nu=2) for product_, curve in curves.items()}

inventory = dict(zip(bounds, (1, 4, 6, 10, 4, 1)))
initial_guesses = {k: lower_x for k, (lower_x, _) in bounds.items()}

# Create Pyomo model
opt_model = ConcreteModel(name="optimizer")

opt_model.item_ids = Set(initialize=bounds.keys())
opt_model.inventory = Param(
    opt_model.item_ids, initialize=inventory, domain=NonNegativeIntegers, mutable=False
)

opt_model.curves = Param(opt_model.item_ids, initialize=curves, mutable=False, domain=Any)

opt_model.curves_first_derivative = Param(
    opt_model.item_ids, initialize=curves_derivatives, domain=Any, mutable=False
)

opt_model.curves_second_derivative = Param(
    opt_model.item_ids, initialize=curves_derivatives_2, domain=Any, mutable=False
)


opt_model.x = Var(
    opt_model.item_ids, bounds=bounds, initialize=initial_guesses, domain=NonNegativeReals,
)


@opt_model.Objective(sense=maximize)
def objective_rule(model):
    return summation(model.x)


# Difficult constraint.
@opt_model.Constraint(opt_model.item_ids)
def my_rule(model, item_id):
    def f(x):
        return model.curves[item_id](x) / model.inventory[item_id]

    def g(args, fixed=None):
        return [model.curves_first_derivative[item_id](args[0]) / model.inventory[item_id]]

    def h(args, fixed=None):
        return [model.curves_second_derivative[item_id](args[0]) / model.inventory[item_id]]

    external_function = ExternalFunction(function=f, gradient=g, hessian=h)
    return (1 / 8, external_function(model.x[item_id]), 1)


SolverFactory("ipopt").solve(opt_model)
```

Comment: Did you see the note in the section you reference that says most solvers do NOT accept external functions?  I'm pretty sure ipopt does not...

Comment: Thanks, @AirSquid! I did read it, I think. It states that Linear Solvers do NOT support ExternalFunctions and that "The AMPL Solver Library (ASL) interface does support external functions for general nonlinear solvers compiled against it, but only allows functions in compiled libraries through the AMPLExternalFunction interface." It doesn't link to AMPLExternalFunction. Do you have experience with that?

Comment: No experience at all with that...sry!